# Creating some instances of the child class in a method of the parent class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance, constructor, factory-pattern

I have the following classes:

```
abstract class Transport{

    protected String name;

    protected Transport(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    protected void DoSomething(){
        //Creating some instances of the type of the current instance   
    }   

}

class Bike: Transport {

    public Bike(String name): base(name){

    }

}

class Bus: Transport {

    public Bus(String name): base(name){

    }

}
```

What I would like to do is to create some instances of the type of the current instance inside the `DoSomething` method of the `Transport` class.

How would I go about it?

I can create a static factory method that accepts the name of the child class I would like to create and then pass it the class name of the current instance inside the `DoSomething` method by using `this.GetType().Name`.

But is this the best way?

Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a `protected abstract Transport CreateNew(string name)` method in the base class, and override it in the derived classes to call their constructors.

Answer (score 4):

Are you open to using reflection?

```
protected void DoSomething(){
    Transport newOne =  GetType()
                           .GetConstructors()[0]
                           .Invoke(new[] {"some name"})
}
```

The above works in your specific case.   Note the use of [0] to get the first constructor.  This is a non-issue for the trivial example in your question.  You might consider using other overloads on [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_methods.aspx) to get the specific constructor that you want.

Comment: Or use `Activator.CreateInstance`.  Note that this will be much slower.